# Padding for table inside div with and without scrollbar

Tags: html, css, padding

I have a div enclosing a table.
Div has a padding of 20px.
If the table size is more than the div then scroll bar should be shown on the div.

Issue: 
Padding is working fine when scroll bar is not present.
But when scroll bar is present then the scroll bar totally occupies the right side padding.
But some how the bottom padding is still applied event with scroll bar.

Question:
How to give 20px padding to div and make sure its content do the padding calculation from scroll bar if present else from border of div?
Note: No styles can be specified at table element. Since this table doesn't aware of the div wrapper.

Sample code and output image attached.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.parentDiv {
    border: 1px solid red; 
    height: 50px; 
    width: 200px; 
    overflow: auto; 
    padding: 20px;
}

.childDiv {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="parentDiv">
        <table class="childDiv" width="100%" height="100%">
         <tr>
           <td></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="parentDiv">
        <table class="childDiv" width="100%" height="100%">
         <tr>
           <td><pre>Sample text <input type="textbox"/></pre><br/>Sample second line</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

take the padding out of the parentDiv class, wrap the table in a new div - you'll still get scroll bars in the parentDiv, but your container div should compress the table to accomodate them.

try this:

```
<div class="parentDiv">         
    <div class="childDiv">                
        <table>            
            <tr>              
                <td></td>            
            </tr>           
        </table>       
    </div>
</div> 


<style type="text/css">         
     .parentDiv {             
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 200px;
        overflow:auto;
}     


    .childDiv {             
         border: 1px solid blue; 
         padding: 20px; 
         width:100%;
         height:100%;        
    }         
</style>
```

You'll notice that as you increase the height of the table, the lower border drops off the bottom of the div - you can scroll down to see it.

You could move the scrolling in to the new div:

```
<style type="text/css">         
    .parentDiv {             
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 200px;
        padding: 20px;         
    }     


    .childDiv {             
        border: 1px solid blue; 
        width:100%;
        overflow-y:auto;
        height:50px;        
    }         
</style>
```